# Implementation of recursive Mergesort

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I made a recursive merge sort code,but it is not working,can anyone tell me where am I going wrong in the code.

```
void mergesort(int A[],int start,int end)
{
    int B[(end-start)/2],C[(end-start)/2],i,j,k,flag=0;
    if(start==end)
      return;
    else
    {
      mergesort(A,start,(start+end)/2);
      mergesort(A,(start+end)/2+1,end);
    }
    for(i=start;i<(start+end)/2;i++)
      B[i]=A[i];
    for(i=(start+end)/2+1;i<end;i++)
      C[i]=A[i];
    for(i=start,j=start,k=(start+end)/2+1;i<end;i++)
    {
        if(j==(start+end)/2)
        {
            while(k!=end)
              A[i]=C[k++];
            flag=1;
        }
        if(k==end)
        {
            while(j!=(start+end)/2)
              A[i]=B[j++];
            flag=1;
        }
        if(flag)
          break;
        if(A[j]&gt;C[k])
          A[i]=C[k++];
        else
          A[i]=B[j++];
    }
    return;
}
```

In the first part of the code i am trying to divide the array into 2 sub arrays and if i am left with only one element, I start merging and reach the top to obtain the sorted array.

Comment: I have a recursive implementation of MergeSort, it's in C# but if you treat `IList<T>` as an array you should be able to reimplement it in C easily. I did not look too hard at your code because it would involve debugging.

Comment: first using a variable mid = (start+end)/2 prevent readers and you getting brain cancer :)

Comment: Then, the arrays `B` and `C` might not be of equal length (for odd number of elements). And the copy from `A` to `B` and `C` is not correct. The index for `B` and `C` must be shifted to begin at 0. The same applies for all other index calculations.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on what exactly is not working?

Comment: you should create different functions for splitting and merging.splitting will be recursive and since at any point two subarrays cant be of same size use indexing to keep track of two subarrays say the index from which you divide one array into two call it `mid` and the two subarray will be [start to mid] and [mid+1 to end] and do the same till `start < end` . so point is work on indexes and separate split and sort functions ! keep the things simple .! reference [cormen the best] (http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/mergeSort.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the end points in your recursive calls is wrong.  You need to decide if end is included in the sub-array or one past the end of the array.  The code appears to want to exclude end, however your recursive calls look like this:

```
mergesort(A,start,(start+end)/2); // should be (start+end)/2+1 if end is excluded
mergesort(A,(start+end)/2+1,end);
```

Comment: not really even if it is excluded in first it will included in the second recursion so in anyway the answer will be same

Comment: If the code excludes end points (as it appears to) the element at A[(start+end)/2] is not handled by either the first or second call.

Answer (score 0):

A killer problem is that the loop

```
for(i=(start+end)/2+1;i<end;i++)
  C[i]=A[i];
```

immediately writes beyond the array. All bets are off, but in any case `C` doesn't contain what you expect it to.